# Business related synonyms?

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between these business related words:

> 製品 versus 商品 -- product
> <strike>商売 versus 事業 -- business</strike>  
> <strike>資金 versus 資本 -- funds</strike>

Edit: crossed out entries moved to separate questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. 製品 vs. 商品

The distinction there is fairly easily discernable.

The key word here is 製造: manufacture; production. [デジタル大辞泉（小学館）](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%A3%BD%E9%80%A0/) has:

> ［名］(スル)原料に手を加えて**製品にすること**。「菓子を―する」「―販売」

Also related is the noun/noun suffix 製{せい}: make, made from.

> プラスチック**製**容器包装
> containers and packaging made of plastic

> フランス**製**の香水
> perfume made in France

Between 製品 and 商品, when the actual process of production is involved, the word of choice is always going to be 製品.

More generally, 製 and 制-related words conjure up the idea of **making/production/manufacture**. [製麺](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A3%BD%E9%BA%BA) is the process of making noodles; some うどん屋 call themselves [○○製麺](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%B8%E4%BA%80%E8%A3%BD%E9%BA%BA) or ○○製麺所; and a lot of them advertise 自家製面 (they make their own noodles).

An inexhaustive [list](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/kanji/%E8%A3%BD/#jn-120903) of 製-related 漢語:

> 製作・製紙・製図・製造・製鉄・製品・製粉／官製・燻製 ・作製・精製・粗製・創製・特製・剝製  ・複製・縫製・木製

---

A tangent: Probably also pertinent to this is the fact that it's common for anime production companies to call themselves ○○プロダクション; common examples include: [旭プロダクション](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%AD%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%80%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3), [デイヴィッドプロダクション](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%87%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B4%E3%82%A3%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%80%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3), [手塚プロダクション](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%89%8B%E5%A1%9A%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%80%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3), [プロダクション・アイジー](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%80%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B8%E3%83%BC), and the use of プロダクション is just another way of telling you they are アニメ**制作**会社. The difference between 制 and 製 words is another can of worms, but in short 制作 leans toward artistic creation while 製作 is all about production and manufacture.

---

商品, on the other hand, means commodity, and is the stuff you sell, with the core kanji being 商: commerce, business, merchant. The word has a strong emphasis on **commercial and economic aspects of business: selling and buying.** Per [デジタル大辞泉（小学館）](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%95%86%E5%93%81/), 商品 is

> **売るため**の品物。**販売を目的**とする財およびサービス。

商品 is the stuff you see behind the display windows of a store, or inside a retail store, or on Amazon. Generally speaking, you don't buy 製品 on Amazon. There may be some overlap here, and on some retail websites you will probably see their 製品 lists, instead of 商品 lists, but when that happens, usually the retailer is also the maker/manufacturer of those products and it's probably the brand selling directly online, as opposed to through the middleman. A general rule of thumb, I think, is that third-party retailers in general, for example 楽天市場 sellers, tend to stick to 商品, while manufacturers might use 製品.

Words related to 製品:

> 化学製品: chemical products
> 家電製品: home appliances
> 革製品: leather products
> 紙製品: paper products
> 牛製品: beef products
> 外国製品: foreign products (products produced in a foreign country)
> 工業製品: industrial goods
> 新製品: new products (of a company)
> 自社製品: a company's own products

Again, all about production and manufacture

Words related to 商品:

> 金融商品: financial instruments
> 新商品: new products being sold
> 商品化: commodification, the process of turning a thing into something else you can sell and make money off of
> 商品券: gift certificate